# How do I allow Netlify continuous integration to get past Wordfence firewall?

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, netlify, wordfence

I have a static [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) site that uses [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) for it's back end. I also have the [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin installed to prevent hackers from causing havoc. I started out without WordFence installed, the site got hacked, and we had to scrap the whole back end and start over with a new database.

When trying to deploy my Gatsby website using [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) I recieve this error message:

> If you are using a security plugin like WordFence or a server firewall you may need to whitelist your IP address or adjust your firewall settings for your GraphQL endpoint.

I have the [NetlifyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/deploy-netlifypress/) WordPress plugin installed. It doesn't help prevent the issue.

I was able to fix this error locally by whitelisting my IP address in the Wordfence firewall settings.

It's not as simple whitelisting the Netlify automated build processes on the website though.

Does anyone know how to stop Wordfence from from blocking Netlify?

Comment: Are you using this plugin ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-to-netlify/

Comment: I've got [NetlifyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/deploy-netlifypress/) installed which appears to be the most popular method of publishing static WordPress based sites to Netlify. It doesn't fix the core issue though. These plugins just fire off an event signaling Netlify to start a rebuild. When Netlify tries to build though, it can't get past the WordFence firewall. I can't disable WordFence or the site will get hacked. It got hacked before we installed WordFence. I can't tell my client to disable WordFence every time they publish/update a post either. That's impractical.

Comment: Great, I've now also ran into this issue when trying to set up a test pipeline in BitBucket. It can't get past WordFence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I figured it out!**

1. Go to WordFence dashboard.
2. Click on "Tools" to view a live graph of intercepted suspicious activity
3. Switch to Netlify and run a deploy of your site (it should fail)
4. Go back to the WordFence graph and take a look at the top row, the "page visited" column should have "/graphql" in it
5. Click on that row
6. Click on the "Add Param to Firewall Allowlist" button
7. Run your Netlify build again and it should work!

**Some caveats:**

***Be super careful that you don't accidentally whitelist a hacker!***

WordFence is constantly blocking attacks. Most attacks aren't trying to access "/graphql" though, so that is a pretty good indicator of which rows are services you want to white list and which rows are hackers that need to stay blocked.

The above method seems to give access to ***anyone*** that is trying to access the "/graphql" endpoint. That might be considered a security issue for you. On the plus side, it meant that it also fixed my BitBucket pipeline issue.

An alternative method is to copy the IP Address in the "IP Address" column then add it to your IP Address whitelist.

1. Go to the Wordfence dashboard
2. Click "Firewall" in the left nav bar
3. Click "All firewall options"
4. Enter the IP address in the "Allow listed IP addresses that bypass all rules" field

That could turn into quite a long list though as Netlify has a lot of servers all with different IP addresses. You will have to be constantly whitelisting new IP Addresses. It is admittedly a much more secure method than the first option though. This method ensures that only Netlify will have access to the "/graphql" end point.

Comment: Thanks for this Daniel - it solved my problem. Is whitelisting /graphql the best way to go, or have you found another way (besides whitelisting every Netlify IP) that is more secure? Many thanks again.

Comment: This solved the issue for me and the site I am working on doesn't require strict security around the graphql endpoint so there is no need for me to try and find a better solution. If you or someone else finds a better more secure way that doesn't involve white-listing a million IP addresses then I will probably accept that answer.

Comment: Also, make sure to up-vote both the question and the answer if this helped you  best way to say thanks 